# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'convertLonLat2XY'

Tags: python-2.7

I have a python file "../sumo-0.22.0/tools/sumolib/net/*init*.py" that containing a function:

```
def convertLonLat2XY(self, lon, lat, rawUTM=False):

    x, y = self.getGeoProj()(lon, lat)
    if rawUTM:
        return x, y
    else:
        x_off, y_off = self.getLocationOffset()
        return x + x_off, y + y_off
```

When I typed in python2.7:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Users/user/src/sumo-0.22.0/tools')
import traci
import sumolib
radius = 0.1
x, y = sumolib.net.convertLonLat2XY(4.8671096, 45.7597116)
```

I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'convertLonLat2XY'
```

How can I adjust this error please?

Comment: Show your import statement. And your filename should probably be `__init__.py`.

Comment: Yes the file is _init_.py. I have typed: impot sys  sys.path.append('C:/../sumo-0.22.0/tools')  import traci  import sumolib. This is the first time that I use python, is it true what I typed?

Comment: [Add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35892136/edit) the full import line(s) to your question, not in a comment. And make sure you copy-paste properly (since you typed 'impot' instead of 'import'; typing instead of copy-pasting can hide actual errors.

Comment: Change your file to `__init__.py` instead (read up on [Python packages](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#packages)), and `import sumolib.net` instead of just `import sumolib`.

Comment: I have adjusted my question but when I tried with import sumolib.net it gives me the same error.

Comment: But did you rename your init file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are trying to use is not a function of the module but rather a function of the Net class which is defined in the module. So before you can use it you need to create a network instance which probably means you need to read in your SUMO network. This is necessary because the projection information needed for coordinate conversion is part of the network.

Your code should look like this:

```
import os,sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ["SUMO_HOME"], "tools"))
import sumolib
net = sumolib.net.readNet("net.net.xml")
x, y = net.convertLonLat2XY(4.8671096, 45.7597116)
```

"net.net.xml" serves here as a placeholder for your actual network.

This code relies on the environment variable SUMO_HOME being set to the correct directory, which is good practice to keep the code independent of the actual installation path, but you can of course use the exact path as you did in your example.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I have executed the code but I want show the results, what should I add to show the results please?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "show", a simple print(x, y) should do?